# The application interface stops responding when dragging a window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user32

I needed to implement my own title bar for the application windows. For this I created a **UserControl**. To implement moving the window I used `SendMessage(_windowInteropHelper.Handle, 0x112, 0xf012, 0)`. But after I move the window the interface of the whole application stops responding to my actions (I can't enter data into text fields, the effects when I hover the mouse over a button don't work, etc.). I tried adding `Mouse.Capture(null)`, but it didn't work. How can I fix this?

WindowToolBarControl.xaml.cs code:

```
namespace Calendar.Views.Controls
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for WindowToolBarControl.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class WindowToolBarControl : UserControl
{
    #region Dependency Properties
    #region CornerRadius
    public CornerRadius CornerRadius
    {
        get => (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
        set => SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(CornerRadius),
            typeof(CornerRadius),
            typeof(WindowToolBarControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(new CornerRadius(0))
        );
    #endregion

    #region Title
    public string Title
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
        set => SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Title),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(WindowToolBarControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty)
    );
    #endregion

    #region Parent Window
    public Window ParentWindow
    {
        get => (Window)GetValue(ParentWindowProperty);
        set => SetValue(ParentWindowProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentWindowProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ParentWindow),
            typeof(Window),
            typeof(WindowToolBarControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(null)
        );
    #endregion
    #endregion

    #region Properties and fields
    private WindowToolBarViewModel _viewModel;
    private WindowInteropHelper _windowInteropHelper;
    #endregion

    #region Mouse Capture
    [DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint = "ReleaseCapture")]
    private static extern void ReleaseCapture();

    [DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
    private static extern void SendMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd, int wmsg, int wparam, int lparam);
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public WindowToolBarControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods of Events
    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _windowInteropHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(ParentWindow);

        _viewModel = DataContext as WindowToolBarViewModel;
        if (_viewModel == null) return;
        _viewModel.OnRequestClose += (o, args) => { ParentWindow?.Close(); };
        _viewModel.OnRequestCollapse += (o, args) => { ParentWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized; };
    }

    private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ParentWindow == null) return;
        e.Handled = false;

        ReleaseCapture();
        SendMessage(_windowInteropHelper.Handle, 0x112, 0xf012, 0);

        Mouse.Capture(null);
    }
    #endregion
   }
}
```

WindowToolBarViewModel.cs code:

```
internal class WindowToolBarViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Events
    public event EventHandler OnRequestClose;
    public event EventHandler OnRequestCollapse;
    #endregion

    #region Commands
    public DelegateCommand CloseCommand { get; }
    public DelegateCommand CollapseCommand { get; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public WindowToolBarViewModel()
    {
        CloseCommand = new DelegateCommand(Close);
        CollapseCommand = new DelegateCommand(Collapse);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private Methods
    private void Close() => OnRequestClose?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

    private void Collapse() => OnRequestCollapse?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    #endregion
}
```

WindowToolBarControl.xaml code

```
<UserControl x:Class="Calendar.Views.Controls.WindowToolBarControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Calendar.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         x:Name="UserControl"
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         Loaded="OnLoaded">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:WindowToolBarViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Border CornerRadius="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=CornerRadius}"
        Background="{DynamicResource Secondary}"
        ClipToBounds="True">
    <Grid Margin="0"
          ClipToBounds="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Column="0"
                Background="Transparent"
                PreviewMouseDown="OnMouseDown">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="10 0"
                       FontFamily="{DynamicResource Inter}"
                       Foreground="{DynamicResource TextColor}" />
        </Border>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Command="{Binding CollapseCommand}"
                    Style="{DynamicResource DefaultControlButton}"
                    Padding="5"
                    Margin="0 0 0 0">
                <Image Source="{DynamicResource MinusIcon}"
                       Width="15"
                       Height="15" />
            </Button>

            <Button Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"
                    Style="{DynamicResource CloseControlButton}"
                    Padding="5"
                    Margin="0 0 15 0">
                <Image Source="{DynamicResource XMarkIcon}"
                       Width="15"
                       Height="15" />
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

That's how I use it:

```
<controls:WindowToolBarControl Grid.Row="0"
                               ParentWindow="{Binding ElementName=Window}"
                               Title="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=Title}"
                               CornerRadius="10 10 0 0" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would provide a custom title bar (window chrome or non-client area), then you should override the `WindowChrome` and `ControlTemplate`.
This way you don't have to re-implement all default features of the title bar.
For example window drag and resize will work right out of the box.

Just some general notes on your code: you should not handle `Window` states in the view model. Instead use routed commands or event handlers and handle them in the code-behind of the `Window` (or control in general).
A view model class per control doesn't work well in terms of class design. When in addition this view model class is used to accommodate view related code like UI logic such a design even violates the MVVM pattern.
MVVM requires all UI related code to be in the view. For example, in WPF this would be in classes or partial classes using XAML or code-behind.
The bad design is proofed by your awkward implementation of routing the UI related action to the view model just to raise an event that the view that is essentially the trigger of this event then handles by observing the view model.
The fact that a UI related action (e.g. close `Window`) is routed to the view model, proofs that you are violating MVVM.

View model classes are used to present data from the model classes to the view classes. They are not supposed to hold view states or view logic.

The following example creates a complete custom window chrome.
The example shows how to correctly overwrite the template of the `Window` and how to use system constants ([`SystemParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters?view=windowsdesktop-8.0)) to create a layout that follows the current `Windows` theming constraints.
The example also makes use of the predefined WPF routed commands and their helper API, bothe defined in [`SystemComands`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemcommands?view=windowsdesktop-8.0).

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window Style="{StaticResource WindowStyle}">
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private WindowState OldWindowState { get; set; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    var minimizeWindowCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand, ExecuteMinimizeWindowCommand, CanExecuteWindowCommands);
    _ = this.CommandBindings.Add(minimizeWindowCommandBinding);

    var maximizeWindowCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand, ExecuteMaximizeWindowCommand, CanExecuteWindowCommands);
    _ = this.CommandBindings.Add(maximizeWindowCommandBinding);

    var restoreWindowCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(SystemCommands.RestoreWindowCommand, ExecuteRestoreWindowCommand, CanExecuteWindowCommands);
    _ = this.CommandBindings.Add(restoreWindowCommandBinding);

    var closeWindowCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand, ExecuteCloseWindowCommand, CanExecuteWindowCommands);
    _ = this.CommandBindings.Add(closeWindowCommandBinding);
  }

  private void CanExecuteWindowCommands(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    => e.CanExecute = true;

  private void ExecuteMinimizeWindowCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    => SystemCommands.MinimizeWindow(this);

  private void ExecuteMaximizeWindowCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    => SystemCommands.MaximizeWindow(this);

  private void ExecuteRestoreWindowCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    => SystemCommands.RestoreWindow(this);

  private void ExecuteCloseWindowCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    => SystemCommands.CloseWindow(this);
}
```

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Application xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Shell;assembly=PresentationFramework">
  <Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="WindowStyle"
           TargetType="Window">
      <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
              Value="True" />
      <Setter Property="WindowStyle"
              Value="None" />
      <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
        <Setter.Value>
          <WindowChrome NonClientFrameEdges="Right"
                        ResizeBorderThickness="{x:Static SystemParameters.WindowResizeBorderThickness}" />
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
            <Border x:Name="ResizeBorder">
              <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!-- Title bar row -->
                    <RowDefinition /> <!-- Window content row -->
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!-- Resize gripper row -->
                  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                  <!-- Window.Content host -->
                  <AdornerDecorator Grid.Row="1">
                    <Border Background="Transparent"
                            Margin="{x:Static SystemParameters.WindowNonClientFrameThickness}">
                      <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                  </AdornerDecorator>

                  <ResizeGrip x:Name="WindowResizeGrip"
                              Grid.Row="2"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                              VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                              Visibility="Collapsed"
                              IsTabStop="false" />

                  <!-- Custom window chrome host -->
                  <Grid Grid.Row="0"
                        Height="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WindowNonClientFrameThickness}, Path=Top}"
                        Background="#FF3F3F3F"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <ColumnDefinition />
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!-- Custom window chrome -->
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"
                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Margin="{x:Static SystemParameters.WindowResizeBorderThickness}">
                      <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Icon}" />
                      <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                                  TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  Margin="16,0" />

                      <Menu shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
                        <MenuItem Header="CustomChromeMenu">
                          <MenuItem Header="Action" />
                        </MenuItem>
                      </Menu>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                      <Button Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}"
                              Width="45"
                              Height="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WindowNonClientFrameThickness}, Path=Top}"
                              ToolTip="Minimize window"
                              ToolTipService.ShowDuration="5000"
                              shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Control}, Path=Foreground}"
                                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                    FontSize="11"
                                    Text="&#xE921;" />
                      </Button>
                      <Button x:Name="MaximizeAndRestoreButton"
                              Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand}"
                              ToolTip="Maximize window"
                              Width="45"
                              Height="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WindowNonClientFrameThickness}, Path=Top}"
                              ToolTipService.ShowDuration="5000"
                              shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="MaximizeAndRestoreIcon"
                                    Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Control}, Path=Foreground}"
                                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                    FontSize="11"
                                    Text="&#xE922;" />
                      </Button>
                      <Button Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}"
                              ToolTip="Close application"
                              ToolTipService.ShowDuration="5000"
                              Width="50"
                              Height="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WindowNonClientFrameThickness}, Path=Top}"
                              shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Control}, Path=Foreground}"
                                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                    FontSize="11"
                                    Text="&#xE8BB;" />
                      </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </Border>
            </Border>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="ResizeMode"
                       Value="CanResizeWithGrip">
                <Setter TargetName="WindowResizeGrip"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Visible" />
              </Trigger>
              <Trigger Property="WindowState"
                       Value="Maximized">
                <Setter TargetName="ResizeBorder"
                        Property="BorderThickness"
                        Value="{x:Static SystemParameters.WindowResizeBorderThickness}" />
                <Setter TargetName="MaximizeAndRestoreButton"
                        Property="Command"
                        Value="{x:Static SystemCommands.RestoreWindowCommand}" />
                <Setter TargetName="MaximizeAndRestoreIcon"
                        Property="Text"
                        Value="&#xE923;" />
              </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer and for your comments on the code. I like (although I can't) write clean code.

Comment: Can you tell me why the title bar goes over the edge of the screen and gets cut off when the window is maximized?

Comment: I forgot to handle the state changes. When maximized Windows expects the window to have a resize border. It inflates the window by the thickness of the resize border to hide by moving out of the screen. If you override the window chrome or set `Window.WindowStyle` to `None` in general, you lose this resize border. Windows does not detect this and inflates your Window althought it no longer has the extra thickness of the resize border. Therefore you must handle the resize border yourself (otherwise the Window will stretch beyond the virtual screen.

Comment: I have modified the window `Style` *App.xaml* file to handle the state changes properly. It now contains the missing resize Border and a related Trigger to handle the `WindowState` changes.